# showing values from an ArraList in gridview and change the textsize

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter

I am showing some items from an `ArrayList<String>` in a `GridView` but the text size is too big!

My code for setting the gridview is as below:

```
GridView selectedItemView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.selected_items_view);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, selected_Items);
selectedItemView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I want to change the text size of the items inside the `GridView`. How can I do it using `Adapter` as there is no way to do it in XML. I am a quite new in android. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like what you want here is a GridView. If you are trying to make grid items that contain text, that seems like either a poor design decision or simply a poor choice of views to use.

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is for listviews and is just a plain textview. It's clear this is not what you want, so why use it?

Create your own layout and pass that to your gridview if you insist on using one.

use the `android:textSize` attribute to change your text size.

Comment: yah you are right.. but I needed it for checking something... anyway I managed it. just too a while... thank you